# Cassandra Command Line Tutorial

Tags: java, scala, cassandra, geomesa

I am trying to run the command line tutorial for Cassandra and am running into an error. This is what I ran.

```
bin/geomesa-cassandra ingest --contact-point localhost --key-space mykeyspace --catalog mycatalog --converter example-csv --spec example-csv examples/ingest/csv/example.csv
```

This is what I get in return. [image]

What would cause this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the contact point as `host:port`. See the [documentation](http://www.geomesa.org/documentation/user/cassandra/usage.html#using-the-cassandra-datastore-programmatically) for the connection parameters. I opened a [ticket](https://geomesa.atlassian.net/browse/GEOMESA-2079) to improve the error handling for an incorrectly formatted contact point, so that the error will be more obvious.

Thanks,